# Fastest way to query contacts with "mobile phone numbers" on Android

Tags: android, performance, contacts

I need to get a distinct list of all contacts from a device and their phone numbers. But wait... We know that some contacts may have multiple numbers assigned, it all depends how each of the users stores his contacts. Here is what i do:

```
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();   
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
    String selection =  ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    ArrayList<user> contacts = new ArrayList<user>();

    Cursor users = a.managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);

    while (users.moveToNext()) {
        user u = new user();
        u.PhoneId = users.getInt(users.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        u.Name = users.getString(users.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String homePhone = "", cellPhone = "", workPhone = "", otherPhone = "";
        Cursor contactPhones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + u.PhoneId, null, null);

        while (contactPhones.moveToNext()) {

            String number = contactPhones.getString(contactPhones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
            int type = contactPhones.getInt(contactPhones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
            switch (type) {
                case Phone.TYPE_HOME:   homePhone = number; break;
                case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:  cellPhone = number; break;
                case Phone.TYPE_WORK:   workPhone = number; break;
                case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:  otherPhone = number; break;
                }
        }        
        u.Phone = ((cellPhone!="") ? cellPhone : ((homePhone!="") ? homePhone : ((workPhone!="") ? workPhone : otherPhone)));
    }

    return contacts;
```

The process works but for my 80 contacts it takes between 1000-2000 miliseconds, and i need to work much faster :)

Comment: I'd just like to ask why you would do something like `u.Phone = ((cellPhone!="")?cellPhone:(((homePhone!="")?homePhone:(workPhone!="")?workPhone:otherPhone)));`.  This makes your code way harder to read than formatting it "properly". Also, have you ran a traceview on this code to figure out what is actually running slowly?

Comment: @Austyn Mahoney: the inline ifs are to prioritize the numbers, instead of doing 10 lines of if/elses :) what slows it down is the ".query" of the numbers for each contact. If there was only a way to query all of this info at once...

Comment: I think there does not exist a faster method to do this. I had to do something similar. I believe,  you would have to iterate over all the contacts and process them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor contactPhones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                                Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + u.PhoneId, 
                                null, 
                                null);
```

This is slightly sub-optimal in that you are encoding the contact ID field directly in the query, rather than making it an argument. This means that the query parser has to re-parse the query each time, rather than being able to use a single cached copy.

Supply the ID as an argument instead:

```
Cursor contactPhones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                                Phone.CONTACT_ID + " =? ", 
                                new String[] { Integer.toString(u.PhoneId) }, 
                                null);
```

The [javadoc](http://goo.gl/5zaM1) for `ContentResolver.query()` reiterates this guidance:

> Use question mark parameter markers such as 'phone=?' instead of
>   explicit values in the selection parameter, so that queries that
>   differ only by those values will be recognized as the same for caching
>   purposes.